# Quick access to "Remove individual cookies" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies

What is a way to quickly open window "Remove individual cookies" in Mozilla Firefox (ideally version 57).

Normal way is menu **Tools** > **Options** > **Privacy & Security** > link **remove individual cookies**. This is too many steps. Any faster way?

Answer (score 0):

### Two clicks instead of four:

Add a bookmark to URL **`about:preferences#privacy`** to your Bookmarks Toolbar. It will open preferences page on Privacy & Security tab. From there, the dialog is only one click away.

Comment: Perhaps Firefox also supports similar URL leading *directly* to **remove individual cookies** dialog?